# The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'Fontawsome' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value 8.0

Tags: ios, font-awesome

I have used 'Fontawsome' in my ios app. While uploading on Apple i am getting this error
"The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'Fontawsome' which is incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value 8.0".

I searched on it but couldn't get solution for this.Please let me if someone has faced this and fixed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t put `Fontawsome` in your `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in Info.plist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to add your fonts in the Fonts provided by application key. So please remove the Fontawesome value in UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

Please find the below link that will help you solve your issue. [Check this link.](https://www.luciancancescu.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-integrate-fontawesome-in-your-ios-project/)

Here is a screenshot from the above link for your quick view.
[image]